# SharePoint 2013 Search Crawl - Access denied: System Volume Information

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

When I´m looking on my SharePoint 2013 Server with Sysinternals Process Monitor and the Crawl is running, I´m getting lots of access denied messages (Filter applied for *access*) for the drive with my search index (dedicated drive).

[image]

Is this a problem?

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is their any other detail about the error? did you see any impact on the search, check the search crawl log.

Comment: this access denied looks like to drive rather then the content of sharepint. what is index location.

Comment: Index location is F:\Index\Data

Comment: did you see which account getting the access denied?

Comment: SharePoint Farm Account

Comment: try to add that account into the index folder( i would go with full control but min read and write.)

Comment: The account is a local admin